# create elements and set attributes

Tags: jquery

im new to jquery and im trying to create elements on a button click and set attributes to it.
here is my code so far

```
$('#myTable').append(
  $('<tr>').append(
    $('<td>').append(
      $('<input>', {type: 'text', id: 'id'}).append(
        $('<td>').append(
          $('<input>', {type: 'button', id: 'btnAdd', onclick: 'AddRow()',value: 'addrow'})
        )
      )
    )
  )
);
```

i know this is wrong so i need your help to fix it.

what i'd like to output is:

```
<tr>
  <td><input type="text" id="id"></td>
  <td><input type="button" id="btnAdd" onclick="AddRow()" value="addrow"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: `input.append(td.append(input))` is logically wrong. Also, pyramid of doom!

Comment: Why is the code wrong?

Comment: you can't append a table cell to an input element, you would have to append the second cell after the first one

Answer (score 5):

You can simply write

```
$('#myTable').append('<tr><td><input type="text" id="id"></td><td><input type="button" id="btnAdd" onclick="AddRow()" value="addrow"></td></tr>');
```

Comment: Inline click handler? Hmm

Comment: @Jack looks like that's what was originally being done, so why not.

Comment: @KevinB if OP knew what the good practices were they wouldn't ask a question here :)

Comment: Ideally, if you're doing this type of stuff a lot, you should look into a templating library.

Answer (score 1):

Use the jQuery.attr function to set the html attributes of the elements:

**Edit**: There was also a logic error.

```
$('#myTable').append(
  $('<tr>').append(
    $('<td>').append(
      $('<input>' )
      .attr( {type: 'text', id: 'id'} )
    )
  )
  .append(
    $('<td>').append(
      $('<input>' )
      .attr( {type: 'button', id: 'btnAdd', onclick: 'AddRow()',value: 'addrow'} )
    )
  )
);
```

See also: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: You can use `$('<input/>', { type: "button", value: "Send" });` like he's doing. The big issue with his code is he's nesting `<td>`s in `<td>`s. Otherwise, it's fine.

Comment: you append the second table cell to the first input element, that's not valid

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var html_obj = '<tr>';
html_obj += '<td> <input type="text" id="id" value=""/> </td>';
html_obj += '<td> <input type="button" id="btnAdd" onclick="AddRow()" 
                value="addrow" /> </td>';
html_obj += '</tr>';               
$('#myTable').append(html_obj);
});

<table id="myTable">            
</table>
```

If you have a empty table else you can use the $('#myTable tr:last').after(html_obj).
this is will give you a perfect structure. Hope this will work.